# El metodo map en SASS no me devuelve todos los valores

Tags: css, sass, scss

tengo un problema con el método map-get en SASS.

Al ejecutar el siguiente codigo

```css
$colors: (
  darkTurquoise: #6bc9c4,
  lightTurquoise: #9bdad5,
);

$themeConfig: (
  linkColor: map-get($colors, "darkTurquoise"),
  linkColorBg: map-get($colors, "lightTurquoise")
);

a {
  color: map-get($themeConfig, "linkColor");
  background: map-get($themeConfig, "linkColorBg");
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```css
a {
  background: #9bdad5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Como pueden ver la propiedad "color" de la etiqueta "a" no ha sido compilada sin embargo la propiedad "background" si compilo sin problemas.

Hice pruebas con node-sass en webpack y en sassmeister y en ambos obtengo el mismo resultado.

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca he usado SASS, pero mirando la documentación he descubierto la función `inspect( )`. Usándola, vemos que

```
a {
  color: inspect( map-get( $colors, "darkTurquoise" ) );
}
```

produce

> a {
>     color: null;
>   }

Haciendo algunas pruebas mas

```
$colors: (
  darkTurquoise: #000000
);

$themeConfig: (
  linkColor: map-get($colors, "darkTurquoise")
);

a {
  color: inspect( map-get( $colors, "darkTurquoise" ) );
}
```

> a {
>     color: null;
>   }

Por lo que parece ser que lo que no le gusta es **el nombre**. Una busqueda con algo de suerte en la documentación ...

> #### Colors
>
> ...
>   A common issue users encounter with named colors is that since Sass prefers the same output format as was typed in other output modes, a color interpolated into a selector becomes invalid syntax when compressed. **To avoid this, always quote named colors if they are meant to be used in the construction of a selector**.

Ok. Vamos a probar haciéndolo caso:

```
$colors: (
  'darkTurquoise': #6bc9c4,
  lightTurquoise: #9bdad5,
);

$themeConfig: (
  linkColor: map-get($colors, "darkTurquoise"),
  linkColorBg: map-get($colors, "lightTurquoise")
);

a {
  color: map-get($themeConfig, "linkColor");
  background: map-get($themeConfig, "linkColorBg");
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

> a {
>     color: #6bc9c4;
>     background: #9bdad5;
>     text-decoration: none;
>   }

Listo, problema resuelto :-)

Comment: Genial. Muchas gracias.